# How to get consecutive number values 1,2,3,4,5 and so on, in multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here I use the pagination JS, and want to take the value of each list (li) that is clicked.

Can i change the multidimensional value of this array into consecutive numbers, such as: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 and so on.

```js
$('#pagination').pagination({
  dataSource: function(done) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      result.push(i);
    }
    done(result);
  },
  pageSize: 10,
  callback: function(data, pagination) {
    console.log(data[0]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paginationjs/2.0.8/pagination.min.js"></script>

<div id="pagination"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy, you just need to do the division by 'totalNumber' then do the Math.ceil function.

```js
$('#pagination').pagination({
  dataSource: function(done) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      result.push(i);
    }
    done(result);
  },
  pageSize: 10,
  callback: function(data, pagination) {
    var numCeil = Math.ceil(data[0] / 10);
    console.log(numCeil);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paginationjs/2.0.8/pagination.min.js"></script>

<div id="pagination"></div>
```